# Pandas Dataframe Transformations

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Consider a data frame which looks like:

```
             A        B        C
0   2018-10-13      100       50
1   2018-10-13      200       25
2   2018-10-13      300       10
3   2018-10-13      400        5
4   2018-10-13      500        0
5   2018-10-14      100      100
6   2018-10-14      200       50
7   2018-10-14      300       25
8   2018-10-14      400       10
9   2018-10-14      500        5
10  2018-10-15      100      150
11  2018-10-15      200      100
12  2018-10-15      300       50
13  2018-10-15      400       25
14  2018-10-15      500       10
```

Here transformation that I want to perform is:

1. GroupBy Column A
2. Then GroupBy Column B into 3 intervals ( [0,100] say **intval-1**, [101,200] say **intval-2**, [201,end] say **intval-3**]. Can be n intervals to generalize.
3. Perform sum aggregation on Column C

So my transformed/pivoted dataframe should be like

```
             A  intval-1  intval-2  intval-3
0   2018-10-13        50        25        15
1   2018-10-14       100        50        40
2   2018-10-13       150       100        85
```

An easy way to implement this would be great help.

Thank You.

Comment: df.pivot(index='A',columns='B',values='C')

Comment: `pivot` won't work because you can't supply an aggregation function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html), then [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
bin_lst = [0, 100, 200, np.inf]

cut_b = pd.cut(df['B'], bins=bin_lst,
               labels=[f'intval-{i}' for i in range(1, len(bin_lst))])

res = df.assign(B=cut_b)\
        .pivot_table(index='A', columns='B', values='C', aggfunc='sum')

print(res)

B           intval-1  intval-2  intval-3
A                                       
2018-10-13        50        25        15
2018-10-14       100        50        40
2018-10-15       150       100        85
```

Comment: @Wen, Yep, I thought I'd go the "extra step" to type out labels :). But think better to derive from length.

Answer (score 3):

Using `pd.cut` with `groupby` + `unstack`

```
df.B=pd.cut(df.B,bins=[0,100,200,np.inf],labels=['intval-1','intval-2','intval-3'])
df.groupby(['A','B']).C.sum().unstack()
Out[35]: 
B           intval-1  intval-2  intval-3
A                                       
2018-10-13        50        25        15
2018-10-14       100        50        40
2018-10-15       150       100        85
```